# Inserting rows to a DataExtension via API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, dataextensions

I've been trying for the last couple of hours to insert some rows into one of my Data Extensions in Marketing Cloud, which looks like this:

[image: Columns]

According to [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postDataExtensionRowsetByKey.htm), I would just have to call the endpoint with my Data Extension's key and send him a JSON with a custom format depending on the Data Extension. The request I'm sending is the following:

```
> POST /hub/v1/dataevents/key:Reminder_1/rowset HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.exacttargetapis.com
> User-Agent: insomnia/5.16.6
> Content-Type: application/json
> Authorization: Bearer *******************
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 115
| [
|   {
|       "keys":{
|        "Id":"123wqe1"
|    },
|       "values":{
|           "LastName":"Name",
|           "Email":"my.email@domain.org"
|       }
|   }
| ]
```

The problem is I keep getting the following response:

```
{
    "message": "Unable to save rows for data extension ID f52dc554-1285-e811-a2c8-1402ec9387c0",
    "errorcode": 10006,
    "documentation": ""
}
```

Now, not to my surprise, the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/error-handling.htm) specifies nothing for this error. The official resolution is:

> Check `additionalErrors` for detailed error messages.

Furthermore, after googling some more, I found the question [`ExactTarget REST API - Error Code 10006, no details`](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/69740/exacttarget-rest-api-error-code-10006-no-details#70509) which says:

> After speaking with support, the error was due to the API key I have
>   not having rights to the context/business unit where the Data
>   Extension lived (I didn't set it up and from what I can tell the
>   business unit can't be seen/edited once created). I created a new API
>   client app in App Center with the correct business unit and this
>   resolves the issue!

But again... I only have one business unit in my instance of Marketing Cloud.

At the moment I'm kind of lost as in where I should look. Any insight?

Comment: In which language are you developing ?

Comment: @Pierre-AdrienDelisle in Apex, although it shouldn't matter.

Comment: I was just refering to this doc : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/adding_data_to_data_extension_object.htm because I did it in NodeJS but I don't really know how to do it in APEX

Comment: @Pierre-AdrienDelisle I'm using the REST API though. The problem appears to me even using Postman.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your Data Extension there is a Text Field 'Field' that is required and is not in the payload.

Comment: WTF... man. Thanks for the heads up - ridiculous mistake x)

Comment: @JavierGarcíaManzano np ;)

Comment: Is this response from the REST API the standard response for this class of error? I'm greenfielding a new implementation for my company, and having a real time trying to figure out some of the undocumented logic.