# Marketing Cloud Data Extension API Insert Unable to Save Rows

Tags: apex, marketing-cloud, rest-api

I'm trying to use my REST api set up in the marketing cloud to insert data to a data extension.

Anytime I try to insert, I get the following error

```
    {
    "message": "Unable to save rows for data extension ID 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "errorcode": 10006,
    "documentation": ""
    }
```

These are the fields I have in my data extension
[image]

Neither of these fields are primary keys.

Here is my request:

```
POST /hub/v1/dataevents************/rowset HTTP/1.1
Host: ************.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer ************
cache-control: no-cache
[
    {
        "keys": {},
        "values": {
            "Email": "testapijourney@gmail.com",
            "SendDate": "2019-06-06 17:18:06"
        }
    },
    {
        "keys": {},
        "values": {
            "Email": "testapijourney@gmail.com",
            "SendDate": "2019-06-06 17:18:06"
        }
    }
]
```

I've found one other posts similar to this issue:

[Inserting rows to a DataExtension via API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/225297/inserting-rows-to-a-dataextension-via-api)

They indicated that they missed a field in their input, which I have not.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I was missing the 'key' attribute in the url before the external id of the data extension.

I also had to make one of my fields a primary key to be able to insert via api request.

Comment: If you want to do this through API without a primary key I would look at soap: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/adding_data_to_data_extension_object.htm

Comment: @EazyE please add your comment as an answer, this should be the correct answer to this question... My colleague developers and I have found this very useful.

Answer (score -1):

This problem happened to me, because I was not sending all the mandatory parameters.